# Text field wont become first responder

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, becomefirstresponder

I seem to have a situation, where calling BecomeFirstResponder() is not working as expected.

Say i have two text boxes in a view. The first text box is the first responder at ViewDidLoad();

At the click of a button i want the second text box to become the First Responder.

The issue is if i launch a dialog using the lines below,

```
var alertView = UIAlertController.Create("Title", "Message", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
alertView.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext;

var negativeAction = UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null);
alertView.AddAction(negativeAction);

//if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(""))
//{
//  var positiveAction = UIAlertAction.Create("", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null);
//  alertView.AddAction(positiveAction);
//}

PresentViewController(alertView, true, delegate {
    alertView.ResignFirstResponder();
});
```

and then call `tbSecond.BecomeFirstResponder();` the first responder fails to change.

If i launch a dialog using the older UIAlert class as below, the first responder works as expected.

```
var alertView = new UIAlertView("Title", "Message", null, "Cancel", null);
alertView.Show();
```

and then call

```
tbSecond.BecomeFirstResponder();
```

I cant change the order of the calls, if i change the order i.e. call tbSecond.BecomeFirstResponder(); before i call ShowDialog, then it works as expected. However due to various reasons, i cant change that order.

Comment: If you have two textFields and you want to swiftch keyboard, Your Need to resignFirstResponder on first TextField and the call becomeFirstResponder on second TextField.

Comment: Afzal, doing what you have suggested, takes the focus out of the first text box, however the second text box still does not have the focus. Also, as suggested above, if i use the UIAlertView then i dont have to resignFirstResponder, so i am still wondering why i have to resign first with UIAlertController.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
    alertController.textFields?.last?.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```